# %3C in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

my htaccess contain this code :

```
RewriteEngine ON



RewriteRule ^Edt.js$    Edt.js [B,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^((.|\r|\n)+)/? index.php?params=$1 [B,NE,QSA,NC,L]
```

i have this link

```
example/file/label/T1=rm@gamil.com&PF2=bonjour+%3Ctable%3EMadame%0D%0A
```

this url must display

```
bonjour <table>Madame
```

but i got this :

```
bonjour Madame
```

i think the %3C is not well interpreted ,any idea to help me ? and thanks in advance.